# stripe manual confirmation + connected account failing (confirmation_method + stripe_account)

Tags: php, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I'm using Stripe's PHP SDK in a Laravel project, and I'm having a weird issue with 3d secure payments.

PHP Version : 7.4
Stripe-PHP : 7.75.0

When creating a PaymentIntent on behlaf of a connected stripe account using the `stripe_account` parameter, and the `confirmation_method: 'manual'` parameter, there's alway an error stating:

> This PaymentIntent pi_XXXXXX cannot be confirmed using your publishable key because its `confirmation_method` is set to `manual`. Please use your secret key instead, or create a PaymentIntent with `confirmation_method` set to `automatic`.

This is how I created my intent:

```php
$paymentIntentParameters = array(
    'amount' => $priceAsCents,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'payment_method' => $paymentMethodId,
    'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
    'confirm' => true,
);

$paymentIntent = StripePaymentIntent::create(
    $paymentIntentParameters,
    ['stripe_account' => $store->stripe_token]
);
```

I followed everything said here: https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/tree/master/without-webhooks

I'm in a case where the webhook doesn't work for me, and where the `confirmation_method: 'automatic'` doesn't do the job too, because the confirmation is done on the frontend, and we only want cofirmations on the backend.

Is there any quick fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to perform server-side (manual) confirmation, you want to follow [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously). Specifically, instead of using `handleCardPayment` on the frontend, you use `createPaymentMethod` on the frontend, use the resulting PaymentMethod with a PaymentIntent on the backend, and then confirm on the backend. The linked doc shows the exact steps.

And for the 3d secure, you need to add `handleCardPayment`.

Comment: That's what I already did, but I just checked, it's actually handleCardAction that I was missing, I'm doing some tests to confirm it's the issue.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Can you please take a look at the question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66983230/9409877